# Change image from internal memory on onclick of imageview not able to use setImageURI

Tags: android

I  have image in internal memory. When I click a imageView this onclick is called now I need to change the Imageview picture with another image from my internal memory. I am not able to use v.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(f)); where v is a view.How do I set the image from the file path "f". I cannot use the imageview name and set it bez I am supposed to creating n number of imageview with same name dynamically  so, I have to use the clicked imageView Id and set it. How can I do it.

```
     public void onClick(View v) {
                                ContextWrapper Dircw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
                                File Dirpath = Dircw.getDir("animalsonclick", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                                File f = new File(Dirpath.toString()+"/"+PictureName.get(0)+".jpg");
                                String Tagname=v.getTag().toString();
       Not able to ---->        v.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(f));
   use this setImageURI         Handler handler=new Handler();
        from "File f"           handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       shows error                          @Override
                                    public void run() {     
                                    }
                                },1000);
                                Toast.makeText(LearnLayoutAnimals.this, PictureName.get(0),    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Can you post the log erro?